# Make back button black on Nexus 4 Lollipop?

Tags: nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop

I would like to make the three on-screen buttons pitch black, their appearance is redundant anyway. Is there a way to do that on a Nexus 4 running Lollipop?

Answer (score 2):

Changing soft keys will require root access on Lollipop (or any other version). You can root your Nexus 4 using [Chainfire's steps](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/11/20/chainfire-figures-out-how-to-root-lollipop-without-a-modified-kernel/). An app called [SoftKeyZ](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.janis605.softkeyz&hl=en) will allow you modify soft keys on your phone.